# How do you play with Master Hand in Super Smash Brothers Melee?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

I've heard that you can play with Master Hand by exploiting a glitch in Melee, what do I need to do to play as it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are just asking this because you read on Kotaku: http://kotaku.com/5577690/the-super-smash-bros-secret-that-took-7-years-to-unlock

Anyway, here is your answer: http://super-smash-bros.wikia.com/wiki/Name_Entry_glitch

Comment: Actually I don't even read Kotaku lol, I guess I should.

Comment: Definitely. I love their sense of humor :)

Answer (score -1):

It can [also be done with an Action Replay](http://super-smash-bros.wikia.com/wiki/Debug_Menu#In_Melee) (gamecube only).  This also lets you play as Giga Bowser!